# Parse date from string to get milliseconds

Tags: java, android, android-calendar, android-date, java-time

I'm trying to get the milliseconds from an string that contains a date, but seems that I'm getting the wrong value. This is the string im trying to parse: `2015-03-01 00:00:00`,
I'm doing this to parse it:

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
 Date inputDate = dateFormat.parse(data.get(position).getValidTo());
 Log.d("--", inputDate.getDay() + " | " + inputDate.getMonth());
```

Comment: and what do you get from it?

Comment: You want `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. And then *don't* use the deprecated methods on `Date`... you're only asking for trouble.

Comment: Please include log file. And log the content of data.get(position).getValidTo() to check if the string is valid

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski when i do `Log.d("--", inputDate.getDay() + " | " + inputDate.getMonth());` I get `4 | 0`

Comment: inputDate.getTime(); it will give time as milliseconds.

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski this is the time i get in milis: `1420066800000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`"MM"`** instead of `"mm"` to get month. *("mm" stands for minutes)*

And **`inputDate.getTime()`** will give the time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
 Date inputDate = dateFormat.parse("2014-10-12 12:00:00");
 System.out.println(inputDate.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add dependencies I would use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to do anything date related.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
```

and use this

```
String input = "2015-03-01 00:00:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(input, formatter);

System.out.println(dt.getDayOfWeek());
System.out.println(dt.getMonthOfYear());
```